# Can I use PVS-Studio Free with Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: unreal-engine4, pvs-studio

Studio developers,

Thanks you so much for your great product and ability to use it free for individual developers.

Could you help me with the above question - can I use PVS-Studio Free with Unreal Engine 4? If yes - can you provide some tutorial or help information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PVS-Studio Free by adding special comments to the files with the source code of only your project. The Unreal Engine 4 files or any other third-party library should be excluded from the analysis in the settings of the analyzer.

If you use **PVS-Stuio Plugin** for Visual Studio or **Standalone**, add the path to the library in the menu Options --> Don’t Check Files.

If you use a utility **pvs-studio-analyzer** in Linux, then use the parameter `–e`:

```
pvs-studio-analyzer analyze … -e /path/to/lib/ …
```

**Note:** due to the peculiarities of the build system (for example, during the auto-generation of the compilable files), this comment will be lost, free PVS-Studio mode will not be available. Unfortunately, such non-standard scenarios do not fall under the support that we provide for the free version of PVS-Studio. If you have such a situation, we suggest using a usual trial mode to assess the abilities of the analyzer.

Comment: Thank you, Steven!